# How can I remove the redundancy in quantifying in "there is a whole number of apples, and a whole number of oranges"?

Tags: ambiguity, mathematics, quantifiers

I am trying to write a word problem, and am having trouble with the wording of one part. Let's say for the sake of example that there are 10 apples and 20 oranges. Call them both items. I am trying to say something like, "there is a whole number of apples, and a whole number of oranges," but without the redundancy. I am currently considering "there is a whole number of each item." Is this grammatically correct and unambiguous?

Comment: Is your question about **is** versus **are**, **whole** versus **fractional**, **whole** versus **a lot**, or about merging the two independent clauses into a single one? Depending on how you answer that, your sentence may or may not be grammatical. As it stands, I don't know the idea that you're trying to express—so, no, it's certainly not unambiguous.

Comment: Just amend the problem with “Fractional Items are not allowed.”

Comment: Repetition isn't redundant if the alternative is ambiguous. The number of apples is a whole number. The number of oranges is a whole number. Don't turn a math problem into a reading and comprehension guessing game.

Comment: a Diophantine problem

Comment: 'Whole' numbers I've seen defined as W = {0, 1, 2, 3 ...} (ie positive integers + {0}) (sorry, the set designator W is usually in shadowline), with subset C, the counting numbers, the positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

It is. "Each" distinguishes that you're referring to both (or more) items.

Answer (score 0):

"Item" is not a suitable word for what you mean. (If anything, I'd assume that if "item" meant anything it meant an individual apple or orange.)

How about "there is a whole number of each kind of fruit"?

Answer (score 0):

> there is a whole number of both apples and oranges.

The 'both' here is acting as an adverb, and means the 'whole number' applies to all the things following it.

> *adverb: both*
>    1. used before the first of two alternatives to emphasize that the statement being made applies to each (the other alternative being introduced by ‘and’).

[Lexico](https://lexico.com/en/definition/both)

Answer (score 0):

"There **are** whole number**s** of **each of the** item**s**."

This addresses the plurality of items and the wholeness of the respective numbers.